# How to return custom message in Enum Anotation?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, algorithm, enums

I have ValueOfEnumValidation annotation which checks the correctness of the input enum:

```
 @Target(value = ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@NotNull(message = "Enum cannot be null")
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValueOfEnumValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValueOfEnumValidation {
  Class<? extends Enum<?>> value();

  String message() default "";

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and class that implements
ValueOfEnumValidation annotation :

```
public class ValueOfEnumValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValueOfEnumValidation, String> {
  private List<String> valueList = null;

  @Override
  public void initialize(ValueOfEnumValidation constraintAnnotation) {
    valueList = Arrays.stream(constraintAnnotation.value().getEnumConstants())
        .map(Enum::name)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String string, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return valueList.contains(string);
  }

}
```

what i have get:
json response:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "errors": [
        "Please choose : {list enum variable}"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I add in class that implements ValueOfEnumValidation annotation:

```
public class ValueOfEnumValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValueOfEnumValidation, String> {
  private List<String> valueList = null;
  private String message = "";

  @Override
  public void initialize(ValueOfEnumValidation constraintAnnotation) {
    valueList = Arrays.stream(constraintAnnotation.value().getEnumConstants())
        .map(Enum::name)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    message = "Please choose : "+valueList;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String string, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
    context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("You write: "+string+"\n"+message).addConstraintViolation();
    return valueList.contains(string);
  }
}
```